# How to res.render react app routes from express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using reactjs and express js to build my application.

See the folder structure below
[image]

I have my app.js like this

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const { db } = require("../database/db.js");
const session = require("express-session");
const store = new session.MemoryStore();
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.use(express.json());

// session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 20000,
      secure: false,
    },
  })
);

app.use("/api/admin", adminRoutes);
app.use("/api/employee", employeeRoutes);

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Api is running");
});

app.listen(PORT, console.log("server is running"));
```

And I have my react routes like this,

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/admin"
          element={
            <>
              <AdminHeader></AdminHeader>
              <AdminHome></AdminHome>
            </>
          }
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/employee"
          element={
            <>
              <EmployeeHeader></EmployeeHeader>
              <EmployeeHome></EmployeeHome>
            </>
          }
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <>
              <Header></Header>
              <Home></Home>
            </>
          }
        ></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Below code is just an example code to give context of this question. This is another node js app.**

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set("views", ["./views", "./screens"]);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "f4z4gs$Gcg",
    cookie: { maxAge: 10000, secure: false },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store,
  })
);

function ensureAuthentication(req, res, next) {
  // Complete the if statmenet below:
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    return next();
  } else {
    // res.status(403).json({ msg: "You're not authorized to view this page" });
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
}

// Add your ensureAuthentication middleware below:
app.get("/shop", ensureAuthentication, (req, res) => {
  // Send the user object to the view page:
  console.log("INSIDE ensureAuthentication....");
  console.log(req.session);
  res.render("shop", { user: req.session.user });
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});
app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("screen");
});

// POST request for logging in
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  db.users.findByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if (!user) return res.status(403).json({ msg: "No user found!" });
    if (user.password === password) {
      req.session.authenticated = true;
      req.session.user = {
        username,
        password,
      };
      res.redirect("/shop");
    } else {
      res.status(403).json({ msg: "Bad Credentials" });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

look here the folder structure of this example node js app 
[image]

with this kind of folder structure, here we can do `res.render` and render a view (login, shop, register).

So my question is, is there any way I could do the same using my original folder structure. Or more specifically, is thery any way I could do `res.render(oneOfTheReactJsRouteHere)`.

Just in case you may be wondering why I want to do this? Here is why. 
Right now everything is working properly and I am happy with that. Till now, I am using `useEffect` in reactjs to fetch data from backend and do the thing accordingly. 
But there is one particular case, I want to login as admin and set the session accordingly and again I can check if the admin is logged in using `useEffect` in frontend to fetch data from backend and do the things. But this will be tedious to in every reactjs page, as I have to check if admin is logged in many different pages. 
So, i was thinking if there is a better way. And I thought what if I could `res.render(reactJSAdminLoginRoute)` if the admin is not logged in right in the middleware of the backend. That would be convenient and I would not have to check about the admin login in the frontend.

And I also want to know if am thinking correctly or if there is some better way to do this kind of  checking.

Can check my github code here: https://github.com/amanc1248/aestheticproject

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, is there any way I could do the same using my original folder structure. Or more specifically, is thery any way I could do res.render(oneOfTheReactJsRouteHere).

Not really. If you're looking at server-side rendering of React then the usual approach is [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) (which means uses Next.js' server and Next.js' router).

> But there is one particular case, I want to login as admin and set the session accordingly and again I can check if the admin is logged in using useEffect in frontend to fetch data from backend and do the things. But this will be tedious to in every reactjs page, as I have to check if admin is logged in many different pages.

That wouldn't help - since client side navigation would skip getting the route from the server.

Abstract the logic into something reusable instead.

```
<Route
    path="/admin"
    element={
      <RequiresRole role="admin">
        <StudentDashboard />
      </RequiresRole>
    }
  />
```

And then have a component like

```
 const RequiresRole = ({ role, children }) => {
     const roles = useMyAuthenticationHook();
     if (!roles.includes(role)) {
         return /* a redirect to a login page or an error message or something */
     }

     return children;
 }
```